# Formating Output in Information Design Tool

Tags: business-objects

When working with IDT 4.1 and when making a query in business layer, is it possible to format the yielded numbers? What I mean is - the output looks something like "1.9982121921**E7**" (please noctice E7 part). I would like BO to display the whole number without any suffixes. 
Additionally, it would be even better to add a delimiter after thousands, millions,...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is `1.9982121921**E7**` the value that is returned from the database? Thus not a number but a string (alphanumeric)? In that case, you'll have to change the select statement and use a database function to trim the non-numeric characters off (e.g. `SUBSTR`, `MID`, `LEFT`, …).

Once you have numeric data, you can use the *Display Format* function to change the layout of your object.

If you're not happy with the predefined formats to choose from, you can always define a custom format. The formatting options are described in the [Information Design Tool User Guide](http://help.sap.com/businessobject/product_guides/sbo41/en/sbo41sp3_info_design_tool_en.pdf) (links to the documentation for IDT in BI 4.1 SP3), section *12.10.23 Creating and editing display formats for business layer objects*.

Right-click and object and select *Create Display Format…* from the context menu.

[image]

Or click the  *Create Display Format…* button in the object's properties (located in the *Advanced* tab).

[image]

Comment: Great explanation!
Thanks Kristof!

Answer (score 0):

Set the type to numeric and enable the high precision check mark.